Winning/drawing techniques for minor piece and pawns vs queen
I'm interested in learning about the winning/drawing techniques of 1 minor piece and pawns vs 1 queen. I've done some basic research here and with this endgame tablebase so any additional resources are appreciated.

Wouldn't say this can be filed under something else than the obvious (clearly N and B cases will be quite different) - use the strength of the queen, double attacks, mating threats. As defender: keep your stuff closely together. John Nunn's endgame books may be helpful.
